# read columns with psql client, which were written with JPA AttributeConverter

Tags: postgresql, jpa, blob, psql

I have a psql table were a column written by JPA AttributeConverter

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html

```
public class MyEntity  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;


    @Lob
    @Convert(converter = MyAttributeConverter.class)
    private Object value;
```

The type of the column seems to be oid.
The converter simply seems to turn  Object to a byte[]

How can I read the content of column `value` in a psql command line client?

Can I somehow bind the converter Java class?

Can I use decode?

Comment: Can you please show the code of MyAttributeConverter. And how do you create the table?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not show the entire AttributeConverter code, it's not public.
But I can tell that its mainly some serialisation lib which turns Object to byte[].

The table is created from the Entity  class by hibernate.dl-auto: create

Comment: What's strange is that it's OID. IMHO it should be a bytea. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663208/postgresql-psql-command-line-display-bytea-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL psql command line display bytea column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663208/postgresql-psql-command-line-display-bytea-column)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli. it's probably another case of Hibernate/JPA not knowing that `@Lob` columns are better stored as `bytea` in Postgres and not as a "large object".

Comment: You can probably use `lo_get()` to convert the large object to a bytea and display the hex values in psql.

Comment: no idea why, but according to DDL is oid.

create table xyz
(
    ....
    value                  oid          not null,
   .....
);

Comment: yes lo_get(cast(value as bigint)). gives me the stuff as hex, but how to get it as string or json?

This does not work:
cast(value as text)